# Convert server time to DateTime class in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I store time as `Datetime` in `Mysql`. I want to show user how much time has passed since its posted.

```
$serverdate = $row['serverdate']; //get datetime from server
$serverdate_as_datetime = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $serverdate); //i fucked up here
$now = new DateTime(); // what time is it
$since = $now->diff($serverdate_as_datetime); //difference

echo $since->m.'<br>'.$since->d.'<br>'.$since->h.'<br>'.$since->i.'<br>'.$since->s;
```

Here is the crazy thing. At first look codes work perfect but after that  i realized the difference between two times is descreasing **and sometimes increasing!!!** **Even if i didnt touch the codes!!** I give up if you suggest new thing i am willing to try. Thanks for help

Comment: two times is difference, because $serverdate and $now are not generated at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Two time are difference, because `$serverdate` and `$now` are not generated at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the problem locally.  Though, the amount of time *should* be increasing, since the amount of time between 'then' and 'now' increases as time moves along.

I replaced `$row['serverdate']` with a string, since I don't have your database.

Here's what I figure *could* be going on:

1. The query from which you're getting `$row['serverdate']` is not actually returning what you expect.
2. If multiple servers are involved, it's possible that the server clocks aren't perfectly synchronized.  For instance, if your database value is created with a `NOW()` in SQL, that value will be based on the DB server clock, while the comparison time is based on the web server's clock. (This is why Facebook and other sites use "2 seconds ago" for something that was very recent, even if it wasn't actually 2 seconds ago.  Keeping lots of servers perfectly in sync without latency isn't realistic.)
3. It's possible that there's a timezone setting are difference between the php and the database.  If you're saying that the amount of time sometimes decreases, this is likely because the difference would actually be negative and increasing, but your code doesn't show that the difference would be negative, so you see the absolute values, which are decreasing.  To fix this, add a third parameter to `date_create_from_format` that has the timezone of the database server. [See Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

The code I used to try to replicate is here (almost identical to the OP).

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.5">

<?php

$serverdate = "2015-02-24 05:26:42"; //get datetime from server
$serverdate = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $serverdate); 
$now = new DateTime(); // what time is it
$since = $now->diff($serverdate); //difference

echo "m " . $since->m . "<br/>d " . $since->d . " <br />h " . $since->h . "<br />i " . $since->i . "<br />s " . $since->s;
```